# Jsf component for html tag

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, bookmarks

Does it exist a way to create a `<a name="bookmark">` in jsf?

I would like to create a list with general bookmarks so that i can point them with links, i would like to create these links with values I take dynamically.
h:outputLink doesn't have a name attribute.

Comment: Thank you romaintaz for correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using outputLink like this:

```
 <h:outputLink id="bookmark" />
```

generates the html:

```
<a id="bookmark" href="" name="bookmark"/>
```

So you could use the ID as your pointer?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Javascript or Output Filtering or a Custom Component

I think I would just use Javascript and patch up the anchors `onload`.

However, you could do output filtering. You could wrap the sub components inside your own and parse and modify the output. That does seem like a lot more work than just tweaking the document with JS.

If you are willing to create a custom component using facelets, a true but heavyweight solution, just go over here: [How to add a new attribute to an existing JSF component](http://www.javakaffee.de/blog/2006/12/11/how-to-add-a-new-attribute-to-an-existing-jsf-component-using-facelets/).